# Error installing NumPy for Python3 on macOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pip

I got two errors when I tried to install NumPy for Python3 on macOS. I've tried `pip3 install numpy` and a few other ways to install NumPy, and they all resulted in the same error. Here is the output:

```
Collecting numpy
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /packages/e1/c5/65b2f257a154c7fabc1895b435e7863a1f0bb1769d3c28f1500976e090ee/numpy-1.19.5-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
  Downloading numpy-1.19.5-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (15.6 MB)
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 437, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 519, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 62, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 458, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 502, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 704, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 228, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 182, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 323, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/legacy/resolver.py", line 183, in resolve
    discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/legacy/resolver.py", line 388, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/legacy/resolver.py", line 340, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 467, in prepare_linked_requirement
    local_file = unpack_url(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 255, in unpack_url
    file = get_http_url(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 129, in get_http_url
    from_path, content_type = _download_http_url(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 282, in _download_http_url
    for chunk in download.chunks:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/progress_bars.py", line 168, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/utils.py", line 64, in response_chunks
    for chunk in response.raw.stream(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 576, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 541, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 135, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 442, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the logs show a timeout exception occurring while installing the module, possibly because it's quite large. What you could do is increase the timeout like so:

```
pip install --default-timeout=900 numpy
```

which should hopefully solve it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to install it with pip3 install --default-timeout=900 numpy